# How to filter a table view output via 2 different buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on table view which looks like this: 
[image]

I looked on the internet but all information is about a search bar and I do not want a search bar but only the two options - vaccinated and not vaccinated. How could I make so that I can filter the table by them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have 2 arrays

```
var allData = [Model]()
var filteredData = [Model]()
```

And

```
struct Model {
 var vaccinated:Bool
}
```

when the button is clicked do

```
 filteredData = allData.filter { $0.vaccinated } // or !$0.vaccinated for the second option
 tableView.reloadData()
```